# How should I create a user in IAM in IaC?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am developing serverless applications on AWS includes: `lambda`, `appsync`, `api gateway` etc. And I am using `serverless` framework as IaC tool. All cloud resources are managed by `serverless` which works great for me.

But recently I have a requirement to create an user in IAM and use this IAM user credential as authentication method for a lambda sitting behind `Appsync`.

I don't have problem to make the authentication work. My question is how I should create the user in IAM? Should I create the IAM user via `serverless deploy` command? If yes, how can I do that? How can I save the user's credential to `secret manager`? If the answer is no, shall I create the user manually?

What is the good practice for creating a user?

Comment: The question here is why do you need to do that (except for the fact that it is a requirement). Answer may differ based on the purpose of that user (why do you need IAM login capable entity in this scenario in the first place?).

Comment: The IAM user credential is used to call one of the Appsync API. I can grant permission to the user for accessing a particular appsync API. so there is no other solution to do that which is a limitation on appsync. That's why I need to create a user during deploy.

Comment: Where is the Appsync API request that needs to be authenticated coming from?

Comment: Appsync API supports IAM authentication https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/. It also supports other type of authentication but only IAM gives me fine granted policy ability.

Comment: I agree with you on the IAM part, but I need to know the source of the request that needs to be authenticated. How are you running that code? It is important because you might not need login entity at all.

Comment: The code will be run in a lambda function. It works as a graphql client and use appsync sdk to send mutation to appsync. It is where I need the authentication.